# why this is a valid query in postgres? is it expensive for the dbms?

Tags: postgresql

I am struggling to understand a part of a query, how could it be valid, and whether is an expensive bad practice or not.

Basically I have something like this:

```
select student_name,
    case when student_name in
        (
            select students.student_name
            from class.checked_students as checked,
            where students.student_id = 1
            and students.stats = awards.id
        )
        then true
        else false
    end as awarded
from awards.award_items
inner join awards.awards on awards_schema.awards.type = awards.award_items.type
```

I want to show all awarded students, this works pretty fine but come to my mind one thing...

in the inner select there is this part

```
where students.student_id = 1
            and students.stats = awards.id
```

as its an inner query it should be independent (I believe) from outside data unless is specified, by doing award.id I dont have that info available (yet) until I do a `inner join`.

Does it mean the inner join is being applied before? or how is possible??

is it a bad practice?

I am using postgres

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `case` isn't actually necessary. You can simply write `student_name in (...) as awared`

Comment: but I want to return the list of the items and whether is awarded (true, false), I believe in that case is not possible, is it?

Comment: Your expression doesn't return a "list" - it returns `true` or `false` depending on the result of the `IN` conditon

Comment: yes, it only returns that, later it returns the list.

Comment: Do you really have three tables in three diiferent schemas ?

Comment: BTW: there is no table `students` in your query. (and there is a comma after `checked` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a co-related sub-query. And no, the inner query is **not** independent of the outer query. The inner and outer query are co-related through the WHERE condition `students.stats = awards.id` of the inner query.

This means the inner query is run once for each row of the outer query - you can see this if you display the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) where the node of the inner query will be shown with `loops = xxx` where `xxx`  is the number of rows in the main query.

If the two tables are related through a many-to-one relationship (for each row of the outer query, the inner query returns exactly one row) then this can be rewritten as an outer join (and e.g. the Oracle query optimizer will do that if foreign key constraints prove the many-to-one relationship).

It's not really considered bad practice, but quite often the equivalent solution using a JOIN is faster (*if* the query can be re-written!) - at least in Postgres, other query optimizer might be more efficient here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` expression is not needed, `EXISTS(...)` already yields a boolean:

---

```
select student_name,
    EXISTS ( select *
            from class.checked_students as chk
            where students.student_id = 1 -- Huh?
            and chk.stats = aw.id
        ) as awarded
from awards.award_items it
join awards.awards aw on aw.type = it.type
        ;
```

---

[ the subquery still is nonsensical ...]

Comment: this actually didnt work since it returns wrong results, seems odd given the EXISTS should do the same